# Preference-apperance similar to Finder, Safari and Mail

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I click on items at the top of the toolbar (Safari) there is a nice fading and window-changing effect.  I've seen this effect in a few third-party applications as well.
[image: Safari Image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to "duplicate" this effect in objective-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If BWToolkit doesn't do it for you, I've also written a selectable toolbar controller that you can find [here on GitHub](https://github.com/itaiferber/IFToolkit). My code is stable (and documented), but doesn't integrate with Interface Builder (it loads separate nibs for separate panes). Take a look at it, and see if it's right for you.

Comment: That'd be nice if there was example code to go along with it...  I'll have a look at this.

Comment: Sorry alexy, I haven't had the time to write up example code. Besides, I've found a bug I want to fix related to window resizing, so you might want to hold off using this for a little bit. Still, if you're interested, you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BWToolklit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/).  It's a 3rd party framework (with Interface Builder plugin) that includes this "BWSelectableToolbar" that does what you're looking for.

Comment: Except it's incredibly buggy. Save often, and have your nib files under source control. Believe me, you're going to get incredibly frustrated, but it's worth it.

Comment: Yes, I have used BWToolkit before, and it behaves really strange with IB.

Comment: @itaiferber, @alexy13: You should both report whatever bugs you found to Brandon Walkin.

Comment: @Peter, Brandon is well aware of the Interface Builder bugs related to the toolbar; he mentions them himself on the website.